# Fencepost conditions and portability for using of snprintf()?

Tags: c++, portability, buffer-overflow, printf, fencepost

Given the following code:

```
const int size = 20;
char buffer[size];

// From the Linux man page for snprintf():
//
// The 'res' is the number of bytes that would be written to buffer had size been
// sufficiently large excluding the terminating null byte.  Output bytes beyond
// the size-1st are discarded instead of being written to the buffer, and a null
// byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the buffer.
int res = snprintf(buffer, size, "some format with %d and %s", 23, "some string");

if (res >= size) {
  cerr << "The buffer was not large enough, we needed " << res
       << " but only had " << size << "." << endl;
} else {
  cout << "The buffer is big enough, we only needed " << res
       << " but had " << size << "." << endl;
}
```

Is this portable and if so, did I get all the fencepost conditions correct?

1 Passing `size` to snprintf()

2 Checking `res` being greater than or equal to `size`

Comment: Why are you using `snprintf()` in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snprintf isn't strictly speaking portable, as it's not part of the C/C++ standards. Windows has it as _snprintf - but otherwise identical.

The fencepost conditions are all fine. Your printf's aren't entirely fine, in the equals case it's going to print

```
The buffer was not large enough, we needed 215 but only had 215.
```

Comment: It is part of C99, and the upcoming C++ standard (C++11?).

Comment: It's still darn annoying that MSVC 2008 doesn't have it. Nor does it have stdint.h - also C99 and C++11.